# Asymptotic eigenvalue analysis for a sparse random matrix

Tags: random-matrices, eigenvalues, sparse-matrices

We have an asymptotic analysis problem for the eigenvalue performance of the following random matrix:
  $H=\{h_{ij}\}_{N_r\times N_t}$,

where each entry $h_{ij}$ is with a probability $p$ to obey the Gaussian distribution $N(0,σ^2)$, and with a probability $1-p$ to be zero.

Then we have following questions

a)Can we use a specific distribution (pdf) to describe  the entries of this  $N_r \times N_t$ matrix as $h_{ij}\sim (1-p)\delta(0)+p\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-j\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}\delta(x)$?

b)When $N_r,N_t\rightarrow \infty$, and $N_r/N_t\rightarrow \beta$ (determined value),  does the eigenvalues’  PDF go to a deterministic distribution?  If the answer is Yes, what is the explicit expression of this deterministic distribution?

For question b), one potentially useful tool maybe the Mar˘cenko-Pastur law in the random matrix theory, but I do not know if it can be used indeed.

Comment: The matrices aren't square.  Do you mean singular values instead of eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes, for a general case, singular values should be considered, and the Marchenko-Pastur law may can be used. But from my comparison between the asymptotic results and the numerical results, there is a mismatch, I cannot explain the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your question (a) - but if you look up "mixtures", it will be answered. As for question (b), the magic words are "Girko's circular law", and the magic reference is the [Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_law)

Comment: For question(a), I think the entries follow the distribution something like the Gaussian-Bernoulli distribution in the compress sensing applications. For question (b),  I do not quite sure if the Mar˘cenko-Pastur law in the random matrix theory can be used indeed.

Comment: Marchenko-Pastur is about SINGULAR values, and has nothing to do with this question. I have answered your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will check your reference. I have another question about the circular law, does the circular law suit for all the distributions, or there is a limitation on the distribution of the entries?

Comment: @WenlongCai that is discussed in the wikipedia article, with references (in particular, to the Tao-Vu paper)

Comment: I run a simulation on this kind of sparse random matrix, and compared the eigenvalues' PDF simulation results with the asymptotic results from the random matrix book, there is mismatch between these results. I will double check the simulation program.

Comment: Hi, I found a paper written by Philip Matchett Wood "UNIVERSALITY AND THE CIRCULAR LAW FOR SPARSE RANDOM MATRICES", in this paper the author answered my question. Thanks so much for your help.